# Java POI Excel creating new column and new rows

Tags: java, apache-poi

Ok so Im iterating over a list and instead of inserting values into cells horizontally, im putting the values in the cells vertically.

It works fine for the first time through the list but when I go in the list the 2nd time it blows away the first list and replaces it in the 2nd column.

if i remove the `row= 0` at the end of the loop, it look like:

```
val 1
val 2
      val 1
      val 2
```

=========

```
int row = 0;
int k = 1; 
for (List dataList: someList) {
  Row myRow = sheet.createRow ((short)row);

  myRow.createCell(k).setCellValue (dataList.getVal())); 
  myRow = sheet.createRow ((short)row++);

  myRow.createCell(k).setCellValue (dataList.getSecVal())); 
  myRow = sheet.createRow ((short)row++);
  k++;
  row = 0;
}
```

Comment: Answer can be found here also - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28405752/3409405

Answer (score 2):

You are incrementing the row index wrong.  row++ will increment after you create the second row.  So you are creating two rows at index 0.  If you change all your row++ to ++row it should work.

Comment: This has nothing to do with how the row index is being incremented - rather, it's all about the fact that he's re-creating the rows at index 0 & 1.  See my answer for more details.

Comment: @JosephHelfert  I am not doing anything wrong.  You interpreted the question wrong.  My requirement is to have it column based not row based which there is no api for....the answer is utilizing `sheet.getRow` after you created a row in the first loop

Comment: by doing that...you can get the index of that row and create another cell right next to it....

Answer (score 2):

On each iteration of your loop, you're recreating the rows at index 0 & 1.  When you re-create these rows, you're going to blow away all of your already existing data.

Try something like this:

```
int k = 1;
Row myRow1 = sheet.createRow(0); //first row of the document
Row myRow2 = sheet.createRow(1);
for (List dataList: someList) {
  myRow1.createCell(k).setCellValue (dataList.getVal())); 
  myRow2.createCell(k).setCellValue (dataList.getSecVal())); 
  k++;
}
```

Comment: Thats not very dynamic. You are declaring 2 rows before you get in the list. Each iteration of the list is a column worth of data. I have to increment the row index to get the data to show in the row beneath it, hence `row++`

Comment: Can you create an array of rows of size someList.size() and use it to create rows dynamically.

Comment: @Doc Holiday. Check answer

Comment: @rozar  I think I know the problem....its the actual instance of the row.   i created a dummy row `Row row2 = sheet.createRow` at the end of the loop and it didnt blow away the first loop

Comment: @DocHoliday - it may not be dynamic, but if you're looking to go about inserting data by the column instead of by the row (which, I may add, seems a bit backwards to how POI operates), this will do the trick.  If you really want it to be dynamic, then do as rozar suggested and create a list of the rows.  But whatever you do, do NOT re-create rows on every iteration.  You should only be creating the rows once.

Comment: @DocHoliday Cool. Good to know its working. But still I have a doubt. even if you create the row at the end of the first dataList. When you start the second dataList. You will still add new row. Is this the functionality you want or you want the second datalist items to be added in the second column i.e the cell of the already created row.

Comment: @DocHoliday Check my answer for the question

Comment: tha answer is `sheet.getRow`

Answer (score 1):

this is the solution that worked:

```
myRow = sheet.getRow(row);

if(null == myRow)
{

    myRow=sheet.createRow(row);
}
```

Comment: You can answer your own question.  But, to do so, put the answer **here**, not up in the question.   You can then **accept** your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a row each time, you want to check if the row exists first.
Something like this will work.

```
      myRow = sheet.getRow((short)row);
      if (myRow == null) {
        myRow = sheet.createRow((short)row);
      }
```

Also, in your current code, each time you're recreating the row at 0 twice.

```
  Row myRow = sheet.createRow ((short)row);

  myRow.createCell(k).setCellValue (dataList.getVal())); 
  myRow = sheet.createRow ((short)row++); // Here, you're creating a new row at index 0
```

akokskis answer is good, actually better, either create them as he did before iterating or check if it exists first.

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate through the first list. You have created the rows. The next time when you iterate you have to update the rows instead of creating it again.
When you create new row, its going to add at the end.

When iterating through List1, when you reached at the end you have already created three new rows. If  you now make row = 0 and iterate through the second list List2. It is going to add a new row at 0 and so on till it reaches the end of List2.

If you have not made rows = 0 at the end of the iteration. New rows will be added at the end.

```
int row = 0;
int k = 1; 

ArrayList<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
for(int i = 0; i<someList.size();i++){
    Row myRow = sheet.createRow(i);
    rows.add(myRow);
    myRow = null;
}

for (List dataList: someList) {
    for(Row row : rows){
        row.createCell(k).setCellValue(dataList.getVal()));         
    }

    k++;
}


     Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
Row1   1
Row2   2
Row3          3 
Row4          4

or 

     Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
Row1   1       3
Row2   2       4
Row3           
Row4
```

Comment: if i add `row = 0`, then the first list will disappear and the second list will start in the 2nd column

Comment: each iteration of the loop is a new column...and the values in each iteration are the rows in that column