# Empty cells from Java to Excel

Tags: java, excel, cells

I am trying to make a program based on arrays with Excel. I have seen a lot of tutorials and I am trying it with the code below, but as u can see in the picture, Java is writing only at the last column of every row. I hope you can help me

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        Row row = sheetOLD.createRow(i);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(i);
}

for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Cell name = sheetOLD.createRow(i).createCell(1);
    name.setCellValue(input.nextLine());
}

Cell test = sheetOLD.createRow(7).createCell(1);
test.setCellValue("TEST");
```

[image: the results in excel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getRow insteadof createRow in 2 and 3 times (because createRow replace all row and delete all cell in row):

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        Row row = sheetOLD.createRow(i);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(i);
}

for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Cell name = sheetOLD.getRow(i).createCell(1);
    name.setCellValue(input.nextLine());
    }

Cell test = sheetOLD.getRow(7).createCell(1);
    test.setCellValue("TEST");
```

more info you can find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213657/java-poi-excel-creating-new-column-and-new-rows)

Comment: Thank you so much! That was my problem!! Thank you! :D